# Colour appears faded in corrected CMYK image

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, compression, itext

I am compressing a pdf containing a number of images. The below code I got while browsing for the PDF compression. It works fine for RBG format images but in case of CMYK format the images appears with inverted colours (as a negative). Somehow I was able to convert the inverted colours but the image colour got faded.

Please suggest how should I proceed. Thanks in advance.

```
{
    PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
    string pdfFile = @"C:\TestPdf.pdf";
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfFile);
    long quality = 50L;
    int n = reader.XrefSize;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        PdfObject obj = reader.GetPdfObject(i);
        if (obj == null || !obj.IsStream()) { continue; }
        PdfDictionary dict = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(obj);
        PdfObject pdfcolorspace = dict.Get(PdfName.COLORSPACE);
        PdfName subType = (PdfName)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(dict.Get(PdfName.SUBTYPE));
        if (!PdfName.IMAGE.Equals(subType)) { continue; }
        PRStream stream = (PRStream)obj;
        try
        {
            PdfImageObject image = new PdfImageObject(stream);
            PdfName filter = (PdfName)image.Get(PdfName.FILTER);
            if ( PdfName.JBIG2DECODE.Equals(filter) || PdfName.JPXDECODE.Equals(filter) || PdfName.CCITTFAXDECODE.Equals(filter) || PdfName.FLATEDECODE.Equals(filter)) 
            continue;
            System.Drawing.Image img = image.GetDrawingImage();
            if (img == null) continue;
            var ll = image.GetImageBytesType();
            int width = img.Width;
            int height = img.Height;
            using (System.Drawing.Bitmap dotnetImg = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(img))
            {
                System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo codec = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()[1];
                System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters eParams = new System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters(1);
                eParams.Param[0] = new System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameter( System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, quality);
                using (MemoryStream msImg = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    dotnetImg.Save(msImg, codec, eParams);
                    msImg.Position = 0;
                    stream.Clear();
                    if (pdfcolorspace == PdfName.DEVICECMYK)
                    {
                        img.Save(msImg, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                        stream.Put(PdfName.COLORSPACE, PdfName.DEVICECMYK);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        stream.Put(PdfName.COLORSPACE, PdfName.DEVICERGB);
                    }
                    stream.SetData( msImg.ToArray(), true, PdfStream.BEST_COMPRESSION);
                    stream.Put(PdfName.TYPE, PdfName.XOBJECT);
                    stream.Put(PdfName.SUBTYPE, PdfName.IMAGE);
                    stream.Put(PdfName.FILTER, PdfName.DCTDECODE);
                    stream.Put(PdfName.WIDTH, new PdfNumber(width));
                    stream.Put(PdfName.HEIGHT, new PdfNumber(height));
                    stream.Put(PdfName.BITSPERCOMPONENT, new PdfNumber(8));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            reader.RemoveUnusedObjects();
        }
    }

    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(@"C:\Compress.pdf", FileMode.Create), PdfWriter.VERSION_1_5);
    stamper.FormFlattening = false;
    stamper.SetFullCompression();
    stamper.Close();
    reader.Close();
}
```

Comment: I did added below code, this somehow works but the pdf size increases drastically. Without this the image colour appears inverted.
img.Save(msImg, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
stream.Put(PdfName.COLORSPACE, PdfName.DEVICECMYK);

Comment: The inversion has to do with treating a 4 color (CMYK) image as just 3 colors (RGB). Treating a CMYK image as just CMY means you are missing the black channel. Sounds like you've got that part figured out, however. The "faded" look probably has to do with color space conversions. There isn't a 1 to 1 mapping of colors between CMYK and RGB so visually things will look different. The simple answer is "don't convert color spaces". You say the "pdf size increases drastically". Is this compared to the original PDF or to the PDF that had the inverted colors?

Comment: Thanks Chris.
PDF size is almost same as the original pdf. But I want to compress the file, which I am not able to figure out. Can you please help me out with this.